# Event Listener Function not recognized

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a method which registers an event listener to each of the MovieClips in an array I have. The method is inside a class, and so is the listener function. The problem is, I'm getting an error that's says "Access of undefined property handleNavToggle", even though is declared.

Any ideas?

```
public class Navigation {

    var navItems:Array;

    public function Navigation(navitems:Array) { ... }

    private function registerNavigationEvents():void {
        for each(var item:MovieClip in this.navItems) {
            item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, this.handleNavToggle);
            item.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, this.handleNavToggle);
        }
    }

    public function handleNavToggle(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var mc:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
        mc.gotoAndStop((mc.currentFrame == 1) ? 2 : 1);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get out of the habit of using `this` unless necessary, which is really only in the below situations:

1. `something.property = this;`
2. `method(this);`
3. ```
   public function method(property:int):void
   {
       this.property = property;
   }
   ```

That said, try amending your code to exclude `this`.

```
public class Navigation
{

    private var _navItems:Array = [];

    public function Navigation(navItems:Array)
    {
        _navItems = navItems.slice();
        _registerNavigationEvents();
    }

    private function _registerNavigationEvents():void
    {
        for each(var i:MovieClip in _navItems)
        {
            i.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, _handleNavToggle);
            i.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, _handleNavToggle);
        }
    }

    private function _handleNavToggle(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);
        mc.gotoAndStop((mc.currentFrame == 1) ? 2 : 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this. preceding the function name, simply pass the function name, otherwise it thinks it's looking for a property, for some reason I feel like this["handleNavToggle"], might also work but why over complicate things.

Comment: Something strange is going on with the scoping of that function for one reason or another, can you post the entire source of that file, maybe just some random syntactic issue but from what you posted I don't see anything wrong.